# Drupal, CodeIgniter, Yii or Django for app

Tags: django, drupal, codeigniter, yii

I'm about to start a new project. At it's core will be private messaging but it will also need:

- Static pages
- Social Media integration - Twitter feed etc
- User sign up / subscription
- Email notifications
- Payment gateway integration

Question is, I'm torn between using a framework (CodeIgniter, Yii or Django) or using something like Drupal and making some custom modules for it. My concern with Drupal is speed and whether or not it will become too bloated.

My background is PHP but I have dabbled in some Python.

Any advice would be great,

Cheers,

James

Comment: Django is an excellent framework, but not supported on all web-hosting providers. The PHP-frameworks can most likely be used on almost all hosting providers.

Comment: Cool, thanks. At the moment the site is on shared hosting. This would have to change if Django was used.

Comment: This type of question is guaranteed to get a bunch of useless answers, as there is no right or wrong answer but there will be a million stinky opinions (mine included: CI).  I suggest Google is a better resource for this question than is stackoverflow.

Comment: I understand but I've checked Google. I also understand people have their own preferences when it comes to languages and frameworks. However, I wanted to try and get a balanced opinion for this project.

Comment: and using noczone.com to monitor your website and servers after that !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation would definitely be to use Django in this instance, it is extremely well documented, has a very informative community, loads of plugins that can be used, for instance django-paypal for payment integration etc.

Essential tools to get you started and keep you moving quickly!

- Git - svn
- pip - tools, plugins etc
- postgreSQL - no better choice for DB's
- South - database migrations
- heroku - hosting that allows you to focus on developing - recently introduced support for Django / Python

Django is a highly scalable platform that combined with some of the tools listed above creates a kick ass experience.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You just described not only Django, but CodeIgniter, Drupal, and probably others.

Answer (score 2):

If your main lang is PHP, I would go for CodeIgniter or [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) . CI is lightweight and easy to learn.

Django/Python is superior IMHO(and provides ORM as opposed to CI), but only if you are willing to learn it, and take the time to set it up correctly (using uwsgi or similar).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, django it's the best framework you can use to develop your project, since it's written in python and really easy to learn. Also it teaches you a pythonian way of seeing things which is nice.

Comment: Sounds good. I must admit, from what I've seen of Python it is much cleaner than PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I started python after php and I never looked back or regret it.